# Autofac - Register Abstract Generic Class Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

In my business layer. I want to make an abstract class and implement by all my entity manager classes.

So I have an error like this.

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'x.Business.Concrete.DepartmentManager' can be invoked with
>   the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'x.Core.DataAccess.IDataAccess`1[x.Entities.Concrete.Department]
>   dataAccess' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(x.Core.DataAccess.IDataAccess`1[x.Entities.Concrete.Department])'.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuNd2.png)

After a little bit change.

**IDataAccess.cs**

```
public interface IDataAccess<T>
```

*Data Access Layer*

**IDepartmentDAL.cs**

```
public interface IDepartmentDAL : IDataAccess<DPT_DEPARTMENT>
```

**EntityFrameworkEntityRepositoryBase.cs**

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IDataAccess<TEntity>
```

**EntityFrameworkDepartmentDAL.cs**

```
public class EfDepartmentDAL : EfEntityRepositoryBase<DPT_DEPARTMENT, Context>, IDepartmentDAL
```

*Business Logic Layer*

**ServiceBase.cs**

```
 public abstract class ServiceBase<T> : IDataAccess<T> 
    {
        public IDataAccess<T> _dataAccess;
        public ServiceBase(IDataAccess<T> dataAccess)
        {
            _dataAccess = dataAccess;
        }
    }
```

**DeparmentManager.cs**

```
public class DepartmentManager : ServiceBase<Department>
    {
        public DepartmentManager(IDataAccess<Department> dataAccess) : base(dataAccess)
        {
        }
    }
```

*Configuration*

**AutofacModule.cs**

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ServiceBase<>).Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ServiceBase<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("x.DataAccess"))
           .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("Ef") && t.Name.EndsWith("DAL"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //builder.RegisterType(typeof(EfEntityRepositoryBase<,>)).As(typeof(IDataAccess<>)).InstancePerRequest();
    //builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(EfEntityRepositoryBase<,>).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    //builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfEntityRepositoryBase<,>)).AsSelf();
    //builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfEntityRepositoryBase<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(AssessmentContext)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfEntityRepositoryBase<,>)).As(typeof(IDataAccess<>)).InstancePerRequest();
}
```

So, how should I register my types to autofac container. I tried many of other topics as you can see the comment lines on my configuration class and could not find any solution.

Comment: From what I understand about IoC is that you Register the Concrete Implemention as the Abstraction you want to inject. As you want to use constructor injection in the DepartmentManager class, what's your Concrete implementation of IEntityRepository<Department>?

Comment: @hem public interface IDepartmentDAL : 
    IDataAccess<DPT_DEPARTMENT>
        {

        }
And than

    public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<T, O> : IDataAccess<T>

Comment: @hem sorry. And than***
 public class DepartmentDAL : EntityRepositoryBase<Department, Context>, IDepartmentDAL

Comment: Still not seeing any Class implementing IEntityRepository<Department>

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Here's my earlier comment again:
"I think you first need something of this form:
public class DepartmentRepository : IEntityRepository<Department> {} and then you can register it as builder.RegisterType<DepartmentRepository>().As<IEntityRepository<Department>>();

Try to resolve bottom up."

Comment: @hem
I'm so sorry about that but I posted a little bit earlier version of my project. So I updated my classes below. And still couldn't find the right registers to autofac.

Comment: Are you getting compile time error or runtime error? Are you getting the same error? And, you seem to have posted an answer?

Comment: This question shows an Autofac error, but currently not the relevant Autofac-calling code (which registers and tries to resolve certain types) which led to that error.

Comment: @hem
Sorry for mess up of topic. Now I modified my topic and try to give you much clear idea about my architecture.

Comment: @WimCoenen I modified the topic. Sorry for mess up.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that Autofac failed to instantiate  `DepartmentManager`, because it doesn't know what to use for the dataAccess argument. The type of that argument is `IDataAccess<Department>`.

To fix this, you need to register a type as providing a `IDataAccess<Department>` implementation.

It looks like you have a generic type `EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext>` which could be used like that. You seem to have done some attempts to register that class, but you did not fill in the type parameters and autofac can't do that for you. You could probably register it like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<EfEntityRepositoryBase<Department,DepartmentContext>>()
    .As<IDataAccess<Department>>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

(I just assumed that there was something like `DepartmentContext` for the TContext type parameter.)